# Updating chrome gives error in console - Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist

Tags: javascript, angular, google-chrome, deployment

I am developing Angular client side application and today after updating my chrome browser I notice in the console I get this error which was not occoring before the update. Any idea what I need to do to resolve this issue.

The chrome version I have is Version 114.0.5735.110 (Official Build) (64-bit).
Below is the error I get in the chrome console.

[image]